# Keras: error loading model with custom loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I define a custom loss function as follows:

```
weight_for_hierarchical_error = K.variable(np.ones(16))

def mse_weighted(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(weight_for_hierarchical_error * K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

When I save the model in a hdf5 file and then try to load it with `load_model`, I got following error information:

`ValueError: Unknown loss function:mse_weighted`

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is solved here by passing a custom dictionary object to `load_model`:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5916
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3977

Comment: Awesome. To save people some time, this is what worked for me: 
If you load model only for prediction (without training), you need to set compile flag to False: 
`model = load_model('model.hdf5', compile=False)`